# How to update content (TextView / ImageView) on app widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

My widget is trivial :

- 1 ConfigurationActivity to choose between 12 possibilities of picture
- 1 widget 4x1 which is composed by an ImageView and a TextView with a text

When I click on the TextView, it launches my application.
When I click on the ImageView, it launches my ConfigurationActivity to choose another picture

But when I choose another picture, it seems that my **setImageViewResource** and **setTextViewText** in my **onUpdate()** in my AppWidgetProvider don't work, the ImageView and the TextView don't change their content in the existing widget...

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers :)

Answer (score -1):

Erase old values, then set new options.
Debug changes alternatively.
Perhaps the pointer refers to the old object.